# Pasar xml a string en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, concatenación

Tengo este xml, lo que necesito es concatenar en un string en python 3.7, el titulo (lo que esta el la etiqueta "fileDesc title") y el contenido (lo que esta en la etiqueta "raw") ¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo? Gracias

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NAF xml:lang="en" version="v3">
  <nafHeader>
    <fileDesc title="William Beaumont and the Human Digestion" />
    <public publicId="d001" uri="http://blog.yovisto.com/william-beaumont-and-the-human-digestion/" />
  </nafHeader>
  <raw><![CDATA[William Beaumont and the Human Digestion.

William Beaumont: Physiology of digestion Image Source.  On November 21, 1785, US-AmericanÂ surgeon William Beaumont was born. He became best known as â€œFather of Gastric Physiologyâ€ following his research on humanÂ digestion. William Beaumont was born in Lebanon, Connecticut and became a physician. He served as a surgeonâ€™s mateÂ in the ArmyÂ during the War of 1812. He opened a private practiceÂ in Plattsburgh, New York, but rejoined the ArmyÂ as a surgeon in 1819. Beaumont was stationed at Fort Mackinac on Mackinac Island in Michigan in the early 1820s when it existed to protect the interests of the American Fur Company. The fort became the refugeÂ for a wounded 19-year-old French-Canadian fur trader namedÂ Alexis St. MartinÂ when a shotgun went off by accident in the American Fur Company store at close range June 6th, 1822.Â St. Martinâ€™s wound was quite serious because hisÂ stomach was perforated and several ribsÂ were broken. Nobody really expected that the young manÂ would survive but he really did. The skinÂ aroundÂ St. Martinâ€™sÂ wound fused to the hole in his stomach, leaving a permanent opening â€“ a gastric fistula. [1] BeaumontÂ quickly noticed that there was much research potential. Back then, not too much was known about the digestive system. In order to gain more information,Â Beaumont performed numerous experiments onÂ St. Martin over a period of eight years. The experimentsÂ must have been really uncomfortable for the man, who was inserted bits of different foods tied to strings through the hole in his stomach, pulling them out periodically to observe digestion.Â Beaumont also removed gastric juice, examining it to better understand its nature.Â Beaumont became the â€œFather of Gastric Physiologyâ€ and his findings were published in the bookÂ â€œExperiments and Observations on the Gastric Juice and the Physiology of Digestionâ€ in 1833. The workÂ is now considered as the basis of much of the early knowledge on digestion. William Beaumont discovered that hydrochloric acid is the main chemical responsible for breaking down food and he suggested that another important digestiveÂ chemical, which is now known as pepsin. He suggested that digestion is a chemical process, not merely a mechanical one caused by stomach muscle movement. Also,Â Beaumont gave insights on how emotions, temperature, and physical activityÂ can affect digestion.Â Beaumontâ€™s famous patient, St. Martin, outlived the scientist even though his wound never completely healed. He had several children and died at the ageÂ of 83. [2] At yovisto, you may be interested in a video lecture on The Digestive System.]]></raw>
</NAF>
```

He intentado usar `xml.etree.ElementTree.XML`  pero no consigo obtener el contenido de la etiqueta `<raw>`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\super\Desktop\documentos\wes2015.d001.naf')
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root:
    for subelem in elem.findall('*'):
        print(subelem.attrib)
```

Comment: Hola, lo usé pero no puedo obtener el contenido de la etiqueta raw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo tienes una etiqueta en el xml, simplemente usa `find`. Para la estructura de tu xml, lo siguiente debería valer:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


root = ET.parse('C:/Users/super/Desktop/documentos/wes2015.d001.naf')
title = root.find('*/fileDesc').get("title")
raw = root.find('raw').text
```

Comment: Me sirvió, mil gracias